# Filtering through dropdown in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down which has options of price range (generating dynamically depending upon the prices of cars in my model). On selecting a price-range, let's say '3000 to 4000', I want cars belonging to those price range to appear.

Here's my change event listener function controller:

```
$('#priceRange').change(function(){
    $scope.init(); //init updates cars[] with all the 20 objects
    var min, max;
    var index = $('#priceRange :selected').index();
    /*algo to find min and max range*/
    if(index == 0){
        min = $scope.minRange;
        max = $scope.maxRange;
    }else{
        min = (index-1)*1000;
        if(index*1000 == $scope.maxRange){
            max = index*1000;
        }else{
            max = index*1000-1;
        }
    }
    //For 3000 to 4000, I am passing min = 3000, max = 4000 and all the cars which then priceFilter function updates $scope.cars with cars belonging to that range

    $scope.cars = $scope.priceFilter($scope.cars, min, max);
});

$scope.priceFilter = function(items, min, max) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
      if(item.price <= max && item.price >= min){
            filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
};
```

But these updated $scope.cars doesn't reflect in my view as I am expecting. Here's the markup:

```
 <label>Make: </label> <input ng-model="search.make">
 <select id="priceRange"><option>All</option></select> 
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:search">
    <img class="carImg" src="{{car.imgPath}}" alt="{{car.make}}">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
       <h4>{{car.make}} {{car.model}}</h4>
        <h4>{{car.year}}, {{car.price | currency}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a good advice: remove jQuery from your project, if you really want to understand Angular. This way you will not fall in trap of jQuery-coding app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the change is handled via jQuery, Angular has no notion of it, unless you wake up Angular explicitly by calling `$apply()`:

```
$scope.cars = $scope.priceFilter($scope.cars, min, max);
$scope.$apply();
```

See also my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/hs9vu0r2/

I agree with @dfsq that, with Angular, jQuery is usually not the best way for handling this type of functionality.

Comment: Thank you @masa, this worked. Will follow dfsq's advice next time. :)